# (Google Sheets) Skip false/blank values

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, flatten

How to solve this formula, so that, bring only the values ​​"7d" (which are in column B) to column A (where the formula is)

worksheet link:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A6:A*1; SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(I3:W=B1; G3:G&"×"&I2:W2; )); "×"); 2; 0)))
```

[image]